# How to set alert on edit/delete of a file or folder in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics, azure-alerts

Log files for my sample application is getting created in the following folder in azure portal
D:/home/LogFiles/sample_application/sample_application.log

sample_application.log can be both edited and deleted.

Is there a way in azure portal to trigger an email alert when someone tries to modify or delete the log file??

[image: Log File Location in Kudu Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Yes, you can surely **configure an alert using the Azure Monitor regarding the deletion of the log file from the App service through the kudu console or by some other means. For this purpose, you will have to create an alert rule from the Azure Monitor alerts pane with the condition ‘ AppServiceFileAuditLogs | where OperationName == “Delete” and Path == “D:/home/LogFiles/sample_application/sample_application.log” ’ with the action of sending an alert to the email id as registered with this alert rule.** Please find the link below on how to create an alert rule through Azure Monitor: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-activity-log

Also find the below snapshot below for reference: -

[image: Log query in log analytics workspace]

Also, ensure that `condition is selected as ‘Custom Log Search’` for as below: -

[image: Azure monitor log alert condition]

`Please find the link below for detailed instructions on implementing the integration between Azure app service and Azure monitor`: -

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/11/01/App-Service-Integration-with-Azure-Monitor.html

Comment: For me this query editor log is disabled it says No data found
This might happen if
•
No logs are configured. Configure logs in diagnostic settings
or learn more about logs configuration

Comment: Yes, you will need to deploy a web app service in Azure and then in the Azure portal, once your web app is up and running, you have to go to 'Logs' tab under 'Monitoring' section and enable the log analytics workspace from there or else create a log analytics workspace first and then browse to the logs tab in the app service and ensure that 'Always show queries' option is enabled so that you can see the various queries related to alerts, various logs and incoming requests.